# Typescript const a = 'a' is not equal to const a = 'a' as const and const a:'a'='a'

Tags: typescript

Ok, another thing where TypeScript confuses me:

Normally we can skip type annotation because we know that TypeScript will infer the type for us.

But it turns out with or without type annotation does make real difference in some cases:

```
const a = 'a' // 'a'
//    ^?
const c = [a] // string[]
//    ^?

const a1 = 'a' as const // 'a'
//    ^?
const c1 = [a1] // 'a'[]
//    ^?

const a2:'a' = 'a' // 'a'
//    ^?
const c2 = [a2] // 'a'[]
//    ^?
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA5HFMD0nXoFDYxEwB6A-HqJLMEjANpwC6WO0ATgJZgDm9TBHMXJ5K4aPACMdNBjgQYVCYVmDipCkprTkjSSxXp%20a4RTHV4AJgBcsmela4UJoiK2LLdRpYM5ZxwlMgA)

So now I know how it works.

But my question: why is in case `c`, it is widen to `string[]` and how is it useful?

NOTE: This is not about how array or tuple works, nor is about how as const and type annotation work. The question is about why `c` does not follow `c1` and `c2`, or `c1` and `c2` do not follow `c`, why not everything is tuple or everything is array, why `c` has to be different?

`c` also widen to `string` which is not preferrable because widening mean not safer, what is the point keeping `c` widen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details of how this works are mostly laid out in [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).  String literals like `"a"` are always initially given [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) by the compiler, but depending on context, these types are either considered **"widening"** or **"non-widening"**.  Widening literal types will automatically get widened (so `"a"` will become `string`) in certain circumstances, while non-widening types will not (so `"a"` will stay `"a"`).

In the following:

```
const a = 'a' // 'a'
const c = [a] // string[]
```

The type inferred for the `a` variable is a *widening* literal type `"a"`, because the initializer `"a"` occurs in an *expression*.  And so the type inferred for `[a]` is `string[]`, because `a` is of a widening type.

On the other hand,

```
const a2:'a' = 'a' // 'a'
const c2 = [a2] // 'a'[]
```

the type inferred for `a2` is a *non-widening* literal type `"a"`, because you [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) it as such, and that `"a"` occurs in a *type* not an *expression*.  Indeed, annotating variables with literal types is the recommended way to get a non-widening type instead of a widening one.

Finally, in

```
const a1 = 'a' as const // 'a'
const c1 = [a1] // 'a'[]
```

the type of `a1` is a non-widening `"a"` type because [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) always result in non-widening types as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#29510](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510).

So that explains exactly why you're seeing what you're seeing.

---

The question about why it is *useful* is harder to answer authoritatively, because utility is subjective.  You can read through microsoft/TypeScript#10676 and [microsoft/TypeScript#11126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11126) and issues linked to them to get more context.

The general issue is that sometimes people want a value like `"a"` to be treated literally as an unchanging value, whereas other times people want it to be treated as just a `string`.  There's a tradeoff there.  And unless people write out their intent explicitly, the compiler has to *infer* what this intent is, necessarily using heuristics that can sometimes be wrong.

If I write `const a = "a"` then I know it will never change, so the unchanging and narrow `"a"` type is appropriate.  Treating `a` as `string` isn't wrong, but it throws away information.

If I write `let b = "b"` then presumably I'm going to change that value (otherwise I'd have used `const`) and so the `string` type is more appropriate.

If I write `const c = [a]` then even though `a` is the type `"a"`, it's not clear that I expect `c` to always and forever contain only elements of the type `"a"`.  That's... strange, right?  Without more context it's hard to imagine why someone would want an array of the letter `"a"`.  The type `string[]` is much more common and so inferring `c` as `string[]` is reasonable.

If you go out of your way to tell the compiler that `a` is of type `"a"` then the heuristics use this.  If you have `const a: "a" = "a"`, now the compiler has some indication that you really care about that literal type, and now `const c = [a]` infers type `"a"[]` for `c`.  I still think this is a strange type (I suppose you can manipulate the *number* of `"a"`s in the array) but that's what inference gives you.  If I don't like this I can write `const c: string[] = [a]` and clarify my intent.

Whether or not one this behavior useful is, again, a matter of opinion.  I can only give my own opinion (it is mostly useful and occasionally it gets things wrong, at which point I can use explicit annotations) and point to the documented GitHub issues.

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to how most programs are written by developers, and how TypeScript team tries to adjust to their supposed intentions.

The very most common case is your first example:

```
const a = 'a' // 'a'
//    ^?
const c = [a] // string[]
//    ^?

// typically later:
c.push("some string content")
```

Should TS infer a tuple, or an array of literal value (`'a'` as opposed to `string` type), it would be too strict and many common array usages would become false positive (TS erroring against the actual and legit developer's intention).

As for the other 2 examples (c1 and c2), the TS team decided to infer an array of literal value, because the developer does give a much bigger hint about a literal value being handled.

Of course, this assumption may be wrong, in which case the developer needs to explicitly type the array (e.g. `Array<'a'|'b'>`).