# Typescript narrow down generic type of const variable with inferred type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

background:

by `const variable with inferred type`, I mean

```
const c = 1 // this
const c:1 = 1 // not this
const c = 1 as const // not this
```

[related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73307386/typescript-const-a-a-is-not-equal-to-const-a-a-as-const-and-const-aa)

So I am trying to narrow down the type of such variable, here is my attempt:
[image]

does not work

[image]

does not work

[image]

```
export const Narrow=<T extends any>(v:T extends never ? T: T extends never ? T : T)=>{
  //
}
const c=1


Narrow(c)
```

this works, it looks weird, but it did the job

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wHIEMpQgdwF4AeAFTlBmGQBNU4tkBPAPgAoA3ALnMurrjJgHYFDgB%20OKS5SKIKrXpCRYyeRmkAlIRYBvAFBw4AemP6AvvqRp4CQgEZ9T7LgJsEmp0A)

so my question is:

1. why?
2. any simpler solution?
3. any better solution?

Comment: If you're only trying to infer numbers, use `Extract<T, number>`: https://tsplay.dev/mAroRW

Comment: Or if you want to infer everything, use this crazy type: https://tsplay.dev/mppeam

Comment: is there a patch note for this behavior?

Comment: Not that I know of. I found that from a friend, and I can't seem to find any GitHub issues that introduced it. Essentially it's just a bunch of checks to force the compiler to try to infer the most specific type for `T`.

Comment: @AcidCoder - this is really interesting behavior. How did you get the idea to chain two `T extends never` together?

Comment: I notice that when I extends 2 times, I can narrow the type. So I think the key is to extends 2 times, then I tried it with the most "useless" extends to prove the point, that is `T extends never ? T: T`

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `as const` though?

Comment: with as const you will definitely get the narrowed type without any extend, so no point experiment with it, nothing interesting

Comment: another reason is, I am creating a library, I cannot expect my user always do `as const`, so I have to come up with solution that can take care of the most cases

Comment: If you know which types may be passed beforehand, its probably best to just specify them as a union in the constraint: https://tsplay.dev/wXqoVN. But if you also want to properly infer narrowed object types, you will have to with the `Narrow<T>` approach.

Comment: "I am creating a library, I cannot expect my user always do as const, so I have to come up with solution that can take care of the most cases" <- this begs the question, why? What are you really trying to accomplish? Whenever I find myself working hard to circumvent TypeScript's default or "intended" behavior, it's a good time to stop and reassess things.

Comment: @Tobias yeah extending the wide types is better, but I am still super curious why `T extends never ? T: T extends never ? T : T`, why it has to be twice?

Comment: @jered, I am creating deep type safe wrapper for databases, I need a lot of type equality check and I am trying to simplify type equality check, I discover this behavior when writing an article about simplifying type equality check https://dev.to/tylim88/typescript-one-import-type-equality-check-24kj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been addressed in TypeScript 5.0 with the introduction of `const` generics. See [this pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865) and [the relevant issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38968) for more information. With this, the definition of `Narrow` now looks like

```
export const Narrow = <const T>(v: T) => {};

const c = 1;

Narrow(c); // inferred as Narrow<1>(v: 1)
```

This acts in a similar manner to the `Narrow` type I showcased in the comments:

```
type Narrow<T> =
    | (T extends infer U ? U : never)
    | Extract<T, number | string | boolean | bigint | symbol | null | undefined | []>
    | ([T] extends [[]] ? [] : { [K in keyof T]: Narrow<T[K]> });
```

Except that it infers everything as readonly, as if you had really called the function with

```
Narrow({ ... } as const)
```

You can compare the pre-5.0 method and 5.0 const generics using the two playground links below:

- [Pre-5.0 type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgJwQewO4B4AqA+KBeAKCmKgB8oAKTKCAD2AgDsATAZygEtGAzCBKAKpQA-IKgAuKIwgA3PgEoiJcgFF6COAGNgWADRSArgFsARnzJRWwBFwDmFk8mQAbCHEYOOtrsAusQpi4WjAbOzhYGLBDcXBDMFgDaALrYSsTkFAmYSTT0TGxQCck5oskSUADehQDSnB4A1hAgyNxQ2ZLwSGhYCdUpUAC+8gDcBAR0YMgIvprIjFawiCio+FBY2BQyHUvdOPL4uBUDowSdyxQAjCMEAPQ3UAB6wmNnaBQARAASKgAyPwDy72ud0ez1OO1QFGsBggwPuTxeEMy0Ig+gALAAmfTvKwId5JOGgxFdSFVbhOSTvEyId76akISQANgAnHS4AAvSQJFH6bhwZysCBJfQARwMtEkVTF4slA0Gg0JTyAA)
- [5.0 `const` generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wHIEMpQgdzgF44AeJNeAFQD4AKANwC44qBKYmuAbwF8BuAFCDsuAnQCMbIQHoZcAHoB+YaLz46AIgASAUQAy+gPKbpguYpUic6ujCgBXYGYvLVN8QG17TgDRwAFgAmf010KE0AXRd5N2sxDW44ADMICBZNACMcTX9sqBYANgBOPKwALxZvR2B-ZKwAG1RgSP8ARwcQFiSOzu7eOAHeGMsgA)